# geometry doesn't create huge document

Tags: memoir, geometry

I am using `geometry` with `memoir` (PDFLaTeX) to make a 48"x36" poster.  However, using `geometry` at that setting results in a 8.5" x 11" document.  What's wrong, and how to I create the size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides its own geometry-setting mechanism:

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\setstocksize{36in}{48in}% Set paper size
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}% Equivalent trimmed size
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Read section **2.3 THE PAGE** from the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (p 8 onward).

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{paperwidth=48in,paperheight=36in}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

I got a `48" x 36"` document using `pdflatex`.